# How To Get Sharepoint Online Migration API Logs (using c#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, migration

Using the `Sharepoint.Client` version 16 package, we are trying to create a `MigrationJob` in c# and then subsequently want to see the status and logs of that migration job. We managed to provision the containers and queue using the `ProvisionMigrationContainers` and `ProvisionMigrationQueue` methods on the `Site` object. And we managed to upload some files and manifest XMLs. These XMLs still contain some errors in the ids and structure, so we expect the job to fail. However, we still expect the job to be created and output some messages and logs. Unfortunately the message queue seems to be empty and the logs are nowhere to be found (at least we can't find them). The Guid of the created migration job is the null guid: `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/migration-api-overview the logs should be saved in the manifest container as a blob. But how would you actually find the name of the log file? The problem is that everything has to be encrypted and it is not allowed to list the blobs in the blob storage (trying this leads to a 403 error).

So the main question is: how are we supposed to access the log files? And the bonus question: assuming that the command to create the migration job is correct, why are we getting the null guid? And last one: why is the queue empty? I could speculate that the migration job is never created and that's why the guid is all zeroes, but how are we supposed to know what is preventing the job from being created?

Here is the code that creates the Migration Job:

```
public ClientResult<Guid> CreateMigrationJob()
{
  var encryption = new EncryptionOption
  {
    AES256CBCKey = encryptionProvider.Key
  };
  return context.Site.CreateMigrationJobEncrypted(
    context.Web.Id, 
    dataContainer.Uri.ToString(), 
    metadataContainer.Uri.ToString(), 
    migrationQueue.Uri.ToString(), 
    encryption
  );
}
```

`context`, `dataContainer`, `metadataContainer` have all been properly instantiated as members and have been used in other methods successfully. `migrationQueue` and `encryption` also look fine, but have not been used elsewhere. The encryption key has been used to upload and download files though and works perfectly fine there.

For completeness sake, here is the code we tried to use to check if there is anything in the queue:

```
public void GetMigrationLog()
{
  while (migrationQueue.ApproximateMessageCount > 0) //debug code, this should be done async
  {
    Console.WriteLine(migrationQueue.GetMessage().AsString);
  }
}
```

It outputs nothing, because the queue is empty. We would expect there to be at least an error message or a message that the logs were created (including the name of the log file).

PS: we realise that it should be possible to download the logs using `DownloadToFileEncrypted(encryptionProvider, targetFile.ToString(), System.IO.FileMode.Create)` but only if you already know the file name, which you cannot find, so that seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 1):

When you call context.Site.CreateMigrationJobEncrypted in your code it returns a Guid.  The name of the log file will Import-TheGuidThatWasReturned-ANumberThatStartsAt1ButIncremennts.log

So the first log file might be called.

Import-AE9525D9-3CF7-4D1A-A9E0-8AB0DF4F09B2-1.log

Using encryption should not stop you from reading the queue.  You will only be unable to read the queue if you have configured your queue this way or you are using the tenancy default rather than you own.

Comment: Ok, I will check if this also works if the returned Guid is only zeroes.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this does not work. I tried to get `Import-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-1.log` using the following code:
```CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = dataContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileReference);
            cloudBlob.DownloadToFileEncrypted(encryptionProvider, targetFile.ToString(), System.IO.FileMode.Create);```
But that gives me a 404.

Comment: I can assure that this does work.  I think you have discovered that the problem is that there is something wrong in your call to Site.CreateMigrationJobEncrypted.  As such no job is being created and hence you are not getting a proper GUID back.  To say this another way one of the parameters that you are passing to to CreateMigrationJobEncrypted is wrong or perhaps even what the parameters point to such as the manifest is wrong.  The migration logs are for progress on the job and so these probably don't even exist if the job is not being created.

Comment: Yes, so I was actually looking for the logs to solve my problem with creating the migration job. When I create it through Powershell using the same XMLs and files, it works without a hitch. Do you have any suggestions about the parameters? I had to guess how to create some of them due to lack of proper documentation.

Comment: I'd need a bit more to go on, I can't actually see what values you are posting into those parameters.